# UILabels are Hidding behind the Image View cell?

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, uilabel

Hi I have issue with Labels ,i.e , I have a XML NewsViewController where i am displaying the News . You can see the Screen shot (NewsViewController.jpg) In NewsViewController i am displaying the Tittle, Date and Description labels , those labels are hiding behind the imageView cell  But in the Few News List are displaying fine   .Can any one Help me ??

Below i have given the NewsViewController code please check

**Here is my  NewsViewController.m**

```
#import "NewsViewController.h"
#import "NewsTableViewCell.h"
#import "NewDetailsViewController.h"
#import <SDWebImage/UIImageView+WebCache.h>
@interface NewsViewController ()
{
    NSString *temString;
    NSMutableString *strTemp;
    BOOL isDateSearch;
}

@end

@implementation NewsViewController
@synthesize arrImages;
@synthesize TittleOne;
@synthesize TittleTwo;
@synthesize TittleThree;
@synthesize datepicker;
@synthesize PickerContainer;
@synthesize datepickerTittle;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

#pragma mark - View Life Cycle
- (void)viewDidLoad
{

    [super viewDidLoad];
    [TittleOne setFont: [UIFont fontWithName:@"GEEast-ExtraBold" size:12]];
    [TittleTwo setFont: [UIFont fontWithName:@"GEEast-ExtraBold" size:10]];
    [TittleThree setFont: [UIFont fontWithName:@"GEEast-ExtraBold" size:10]];
    // [[UIColor redColor] set];
    [datepickerTittle setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"GEEast-ExtraBold" size:12]];
    // [datepickerTittle.textColor= [UIColor yellowColor]];

    isDateSearch=NO;
    self.arrTitles =[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    self.arrDescription=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    self.arrImages=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    self.arrDate=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    self.arrUrls=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    self.arrDateSearch=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    //[self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(requestingForNews:) withObject:nil];

    // dispatch_async( dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), s^{
    self.spinnerView.hidden=YES;
    [self makeRequestForNews];
    //  self.spinnerView.stopAnimating;
    //});

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    [self imagedownloader:@"http://www.shura.bh/MediaCenter/News/"];
}
-(void)requestingForNews:(id)sender
{
    [self makeRequestForNews];
}
-(void) imagedownloader : (NSString *)urlStringOfImage
{
    dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0ul);
    dispatch_async(queue, ^{
        //downlaod image
        NSURL *imageUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:urlStringOfImage];
        NSData  *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imageUrl];
        UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

            UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 50 )];
            imageView.image = image;
            [self.view addSubview:imageView];
        });
    });
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

#pragma  mark - make request for news
-(void)makeRequestForNews
{

    NSURL *url =[NSURL URLWithString:self.strNewsApi];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    //After making request the apparent thing is expecting the response that may be expected response or an Error. so create those objects and intialize them with NULL.
    NSURLResponse *response = NULL;
    NSError *requestError =NULL;
    //Once you have response with you , Capture YOur Responce data using NsData.

    NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&requestError];

    //Convert the respnse Data into Response String.

    NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    //Now We can start parsing the Data using XMl parser . you need XML parser in-order to use the below class method "dictionaryFOrXMLString".

    NSError *parserError = NULL;

    //XML parsing

    NSXMLParser *xmlParser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData:responseData];
    [xmlParser setDelegate:self];
    [xmlParser parse];

    //    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:url];
    //    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
    //    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];

    //NSDictionary *xmlDict = [XMLReader dictionaryForXMLString:responseString error:NULL];

    //once you have xmlDict handy, you can pass this to the any ViewController (Like table view) to populate the Data.
}

- (void)parserDidEndDocument:(NSXMLParser *)parser {

}
-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict
{


    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"ShuraNews"])
    {

    }
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"PUBLISHINGPAGEIMAGE"])
    {

    }
    strTemp=[NSMutableString new];
}
-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string
{
    //temString =string;
    [strTemp appendString:string];
}
-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName
{
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"TITLE"])
    {
        NSLog(@"temstring=== %@", strTemp);
        [self.arrTitles addObject:strTemp];
    }
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"PUBLISHINGPAGECONTENT"])
    {
        NSLog(@"temstring=== %@", strTemp);
        [self.arrDescription addObject:strTemp];
    }
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"NEWSARTICLEDATE"])
    {
        NSLog(@"temstring=== %@", strTemp);
        [self.arrDate addObject:strTemp];
    }
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"PUBLISHINGPAGEIMAGE"])
    {

        NSLog(@"temstring=== %@", strTemp);
        [self.arrImages addObject:strTemp];
    }
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"ShuraNews"])
    {
        [self.tblNews reloadData];
        // self.spinnerView.hidden=YES;
    }
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"URL"])
    {
        [self.arrUrls addObject:strTemp];
    }

}

#pragma mark - TabeView Datasource//delegate method

-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if (isDateSearch)
    {
        return [self.arrDateSearch count];
    }
    else{
        return [self.arrTitles count];
    }
}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [tableView setSeparatorInset:UIEdgeInsetsZero];
    static NSString *cellIdentifier=@"cellNews";
    NewsTableViewCell *cell=(NewsTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[NewsTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
        // cell.NewsTableViewCell.textColor = UIColorFromRGB(0x000000);
        cell.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];


    }

    if( [indexPath row] % 2){
        cell.contentView.backgroundColor =UIColorFromRGB(0Xffffff);

    }
    else{
        cell.contentView.backgroundColor =UIColorFromRGB (0Xdcdcdc);
    }

    //selectbackground color start
    UIView *NewsTableViewCell = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:cell.frame];
    NewsTableViewCell.backgroundColor = UIColorFromRGB(0Xdcdcdc);
    cell.selectedBackgroundView = NewsTableViewCell; //select background colro end
    cell.lblTitles.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"GEEast-ExtraBold" size:12];
    if (isDateSearch)
    {
        cell.lblTitles.text=[[self.arrDateSearch objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"title"];
    }
    else{
        cell.lblTitles.text=[self.arrTitles objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }
    cell.lblDescription.font =[UIFont fontWithName:@"GE SS Unique" size:12];
    cell.lblDate.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"GE SS Unique" size:12];
    if (isDateSearch)
    {
        cell.lblDescription.text=[[self.arrDateSearch objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"des"];
    }
    else{
        cell.lblDescription.text=[self.arrDescription objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }
    cell.lblDate.text=[self.arrDate objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.lblTitles.textAlignment= NSTextAlignmentRight;
    cell.lblDate.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentRight;
    cell.lblDescription.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentRight;
    //SDWebImage Code for lazy loader
    [cell.imgNews setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[self.arrImages objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@""]];
    // cell.imgNews.image=[UIImage imageWithData:data];
    cell.imgNews.layer.borderColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
    cell.imgNews.layer.borderWidth = 2.0;
    [PickerContainer setHidden:YES];
    if (!cell.imgNews.image)
    {
        cell.lblTitles.frame=CGRectMake(cell.lblTitles.frame.origin.x, cell.lblTitles.frame.origin.y, 283, cell.lblTitles.frame.size.height);
        cell.lblDate.frame=CGRectMake(cell.lblDate.frame.origin.x, cell.lblDate.frame.origin.y, 286, cell.lblDate.frame.size.height);
        cell.lblDescription.frame=CGRectMake(cell.lblDescription.frame.origin.x, cell.lblDescription.frame.origin.y, 281, cell.lblDescription.frame.size.height);
        cell.imgNews.layer.borderColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
        cell.imgNews.layer.borderWidth = 0;
    }
    return cell;
}
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSDictionary *dict=nil;
    if (isDateSearch)
    {
        //dict=[[NSDictionary alloc]initWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[self.arrDateSearch objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"title"]],@"title",[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[self.arrDateSearch objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"des"]],@"img",[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[self.arrDescription objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]],@"Des",[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[self.arrUrls objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]],@"url", nil];
    }
    else{
        dict=[[NSDictionary alloc]initWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",
                                                          [self.arrTitles objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]],@"title",[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",
                                                                                                                  [self.arrImages objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]],@"img",[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",
                                                                                                                                                                        [self.arrDescription objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]],@"Des",[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[self.arrUrls objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]],@"url", nil];
    }
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"NewsDetailsID" sender:dict];
}

-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"NewsDetailsID"])
    {
        ((NewDetailsViewController *)segue.destinationViewController).strTitle=[sender objectForKey:@"title"];
        ((NewDetailsViewController *)segue.destinationViewController).strDetailImage=[sender objectForKey:@"img"];
        ((NewDetailsViewController *)segue.destinationViewController).strDescription=[sender objectForKey:@"Des"];//strUrl
        ((NewDetailsViewController *)segue.destinationViewController).strUrl=[sender objectForKey:@"url"];
    }
}

- (IBAction)backBtnClicked:(id)sender {
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}

- (IBAction)DatePickerBt:(id)sender {
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.3];
    PickerContainer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 150, 320, 261);
    [PickerContainer setHidden:NO];
}
- (IBAction)HideButton:(id)sender
{
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.3];
    PickerContainer.frame = CGRectMake(0,600, 320, 261);
    [UIView commitAnimations];

    if ([self.arrDateSearch count])
    {
        [self.arrDateSearch removeAllObjects];
    }
    if ([self.arrDate count])
    {
        for (int i=0; i<[self.arrDate count]; i++)
        {
            NSLog(@"arrdate === %@",self.arrDate);

            NSArray *arrDateStr=[[self.arrDate objectAtIndex:i] componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];
            NSArray *arrDat=[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[arrDateStr objectAtIndex:0]] componentsSeparatedByString:@"/"];

            NSString *strDat=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@-%@-%@",[arrDat objectAtIndex:2],[arrDat objectAtIndex:1],[arrDat objectAtIndex:0]];
            NSString *strPicDat=[[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",self.datepicker.date]componentsSeparatedByString:@" "]objectAtIndex:0];
            NSLog(@" strpic date === %@",strPicDat);
            if ([strDat isEqualToString:strPicDat])
            {
                isDateSearch=YES;
                NSDictionary *dictTemp=[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[self.arrTitles objectAtIndex:i],@"title",[self.arrDescription objectAtIndex:i],@"des",[self.arrImages objectAtIndex:i],@"img", nil];
                [self.arrDateSearch addObject:dictTemp];
                NSLog(@"dates equal");
            }

        }

        [self.tblNews reloadData];

    }
}
- (IBAction)ReloadButton:(id)sender {


}
@end
```

Below i have given the Screen shots

**NewsViewController** [Link](http://www.innovativeoranges.com/newsviewcontroller.jpg) Here

**DetailsViewController** [Link](http://www.innovativeoranges.com/detailviewcontroller.jpg) here

Comment: please show a screenshot of your Interface Builder view of the UITableViewCell that makes up one of the tableview items. :D

Comment: Hi Below i have given the Interface Scren shots please check it . 1).http://www.innovativeoranges.com/Newsviewcontroller%20Attribute%20INspector.png 2.)http://www.innovativeoranges.com/detaislscreen%20Attribute%20insector.png 3.)http://www.innovativeoranges.com/detaislscreen%20Size%20Inspector.png 4.)http://www.innovativeoranges.com/Newsviewcontroller%20Size%20inspector.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two questions here. Ill answer the one about the tableview.

The `SDWebImage` category on `UIImageView` (`UIImageView+WebCache`)  is an async API , hence when you work out whether there is an image there and arrange your text frame it always evaluates to NO

```
[cell.imgNews setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[self.arrImages objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@""]];
...
if (!cell.imgNews.image)
{
    //setup text frame
}
```

what you are calling is a convenience method for this...

`- (void)setImageWithURL:(NSURL *)url placeholderImage:(UIImage *)placeholder options:(SDWebImageOptions)options progress:(SDWebImageDownloaderProgressBlock)progressBlock completed:(SDWebImageCompletedBlock)completedBlock;`

so try this...

```
[cell.imgNews setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[self.arrImages objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]] 
placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@""] 
completed:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error, SDImageCacheType cacheType) {
    ...
    if (image) {
    //setup text frame for image
    }
    else {
   //setup text for no image as cell is recycled and may have held image previously
    }

}];
```

Comment: Hi I have small doubt , from the XML all the image are coming that i can see in the Debugger Area, But when it comes in the Screen it displaying only 2-3 images only why like that ? is any problem with XML Or In my code ??

Answer (score 0):

Please view your InterfaceBuilder Screenshots 2 and 3.

The Large image (3) has the autoresizing mask set so that the margin to the right is maintained. #
It looks like this

_ | _

The Label besides the small image in the UITableViewCell however only mainains the margins to the top and the left. Set to keep it on the right as well and it won't overflow anymore.
Make it look like the mask above.

Of course you'd have to do this for all 3 labels. Alternatvively you could wrap the 3 labels in a view and only do the autoresizing mask stuff for this container and make the labels fill out the entire width of the container.

Answer (score 0):

I will answer the question regarding the cells in "NewsViewController".
Using `[UIImage imageNamed:@""]` is equivalent to passing `nil`. UIImage class will not find an image with a name of empty string, so it will return `nil`.
When you check `cell.imgNews`'s image, it will be `nil` as the real image is still not loaded yet.

You have two options:
1- Use a placeholder image.
2- Check for the image url instead of the image itself. like `if (![self.arrImages objectAtIndex:indexPath.row])`.

Note: Make sure the data arrays have the same length. If one of them has different length, you will get out of bounds exception. One way of solving this is using a custom class that hold all related information. Then build an array of it.

Comment: Hi Thanks for your Answer , Actually the image loading from XML But in Simulator its displaying empty cell only ? what was the issue ? you can have look my Screen shot here http://innovativeoranges.com/imageloading%20copy.jpg

Comment: Are you sure you are setting the `image`in the completion block? `cell.imgNews.image = image;`

Comment: Yes i am sure , The thing is Only 2or 3 images only its displaying in the cell rest all are empty but in the debugger Area all images are loading, i don't know with this ? you can see the Screen shot here  http://innovativeoranges.com/fewimages.png

Comment: I tried an image from shura's website in the sample project with SDWebImage and it worked without a problem. It only takes time to download the iage and display it. Ah and you don't need to set the image in the completion block. Also, I found that the `setImageWithURL:.....` methods is deprecated and you should use `sd_setImageWithURL:....` to avoid any future errors when they remove the deprecated methods. I can't put my hand on the problem right now. But I found a good article http://1actobacillus.tumblr.com/post/45647315415/sdwebimage-and-lazy-loading-of-images-in you can try this approach.

Comment: Actually i found the error why All images are not displaying , The problem is if image name is like this "dsc_2855.jpg " its displaying, But if image is name is like this   "الوفد%20الصيني%20علاقة%20الشورى%20والاستشاري%20الصيني%20وطيدة%20أرسيت%20بدعم%20من%20قيادة%20البلدين%20الصديقين.jpg" its not reading so what would be the solution for this ??? Any idea ?

Comment: I think this is an encoding problem. Try `[NSURL URLWithString:[[self.arrImages objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];`

Comment: I used the above code now the app looking like this http://www.innovativeoranges.com/Screen%20Shot%202014-06-23%20at%2012.27.11.png. but the image cell space was hidden . and few tittle are overlapping please have look in the screen shot . ? And we cannot display the Arabic named images ? is there any another solution for this ?

Comment: Yeah, I found that the above code doesn't encode reserved characters like "&" and "(". Use this method instead if you are suporting iOS 7 and above `[NSURL URLWithString:[[_objects objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters:[NSCharacterSet URLPathAllowedCharacterSet]]]`. If you want to support iOS 6 use this method `[NSURL URLWithString:(NSString *)CFBridgingRelease(CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(NULL, (CFStringRef) [_objects objectAtIndex:indexPath.row], NULL, NULL, kCFStringEncodingUTF8))]`

Comment: HI ,The above both methods i tried but  still same problem .. ??

Comment: I tried them personally with images from shura.bh that contains Arabic characters and they are working.

Comment: [cell.imgNews setImageWithURL : [NSURL URLWithString:(NSString *)CFBridgingRelease(CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(NULL, (CFStringRef) [arrImages objectAtIndex:indexPath.row], NULL, NULL, kCFStringEncodingUTF8))] AND  [cell.imgNews setImageWithURL: [NSURL URLWithString:[[arrImages objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters:[NSCharacterSet URLPathAllowedCharacterSet]]] like this i tried both the methods . but not displaying images?

Comment: Try logging the result string and URL to see if the URLs are created. `NSLog(@"Original URL:%@ \n Encoded URL:%@ \n URL object: %@", [_objects objectAtIndex:indexPath.row], [[_objects objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters:[NSCharacterSet URLPathAllowedCharacterSet]], [NSURL URLWithString:[[_objects objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters:[NSCharacterSet URLPathAllowedCharacterSet]]]);`

Comment: H, I am trying above code but i am getting some error , As per my code how to call NSLog , my code is like this '[NSURL URLWithString:[[self.arrImages objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]]'. so how can i embed with your  reference code ? can you give me some example please ??

Comment: i tried your code like this : cell.imgNews = [NSURL URLWithString:[self.arrImages objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    
    NSLog(@"Original URL:%@ \n Encoded URL:%@ \n URL object: %@", [arrImages objectAtIndex:indexPath.row], [[arrImages objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters:[NSCharacterSet URLPathAllowedCharacterSet]], [NSURL URLWithString:[[arrImages objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters:[NSCharacterSet URLPathAllowedCharacterSet]]]); but in the Debugger Area the image url is coming URL object&Encoded URL:?

Comment: To make sure I understood you right, only the original URL is returned and the encoded and the URL object are not created, right? If so, this means the encoding failed. If you can give me a sample project that reproduce this problem, I can tinker with it to figure out what is the problem.

Comment: Hi , The url object created , in the Debugger the  URL object  is coming like this : URL object: http%3A//www.shura.bh/mediacenter/news/committees/utilities/publishingimages/%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%B5%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%AD%2520%2 ... 9%8A.jpg AND Encode url also coming same like that in the Debugger Area

Comment: OK this means that the encoding messed up the URL by encoding some of the characters that shouldn't be encoded like the colon ":" after "http". In this case we will encode only the last part (component) of the URL. `NSString *path = [arrImages objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSString *encodedLastPathComponent = [path.lastPathComponent stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters:[NSCharacterSet URLPathAllowedCharacterSet]];
    path = [path stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:path.lastPathComponent withString:encodedLastPathComponent];
    [NSURL URLWithString:path];`

Comment: Hi ,I tried the above code , now its displaying empty cell ??

Comment: Can you send me the original and the resulted strings?

Comment: This is my Image string from XML    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"PUBLISHINGPAGEIMAGE"])
    {
        
        NSLog(@"temstring=== %@", strTemp);
        [self.arrImages addObject:strTemp];
    } . And this my iamgeview cell  [cell.imgNews setImageWithURL: [NSURL URLWithString:[self.arrImages objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]

Comment: In my question i have given my NewsViewController.m full code please check in that .

Comment: I meant the image URL before and after encoding as I don't have the API URL to get the data you have problem with. I wanted these data to check how the code I gave you encoded the URLs. Another option, give me the API URL if it is not confidential and I will try to make it work and send you a sample project that has it work.